# Changed name of database entity-framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.**

I changed name of database. First when I have got PoliNameDatabase everything working correct but when I changed name of database in web.config PoliNameDatabaseTwo database does not work correct. I can see wrong connection to database even I change name in web.config (example: PoliNameDatabase.dbo.MyProcedure) where I have to also change this name of database in entity-framework?

[image]

Comment: Try debugging your program and seeing where it's getting the connection string from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `ObjectContext` or `DbContext`, there will be a default name for the connection string. The connection string should be the only thing you should alter to get the right database. What usually happen is that, for instance, if you have an assembly for `Model` and another for your application, you would have to change this connection string twice: In the model assembly, so that it would set the default name right and work properly in the designer, and in your `web.config` or `app.config` so the application will get in in runtime.

When you have the `ObjectContext` object, you can inspect the connection string from the property `[your_object_context].ConnectionString`. From `DbContext`, you would get it from `[your_db_context].Database.Connection.ConnectionString`.

After you have the connection string name. Inspect `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` for checking it out.